# KnockoutJS - Set the initial value of a select list based on the output of computed observables

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS to create a cascade of select controls based on a product category, product manufacturer and product model.

This works fine and the cascade functions as expected.

However the last drop down is populated by a choice of 4 values and I want the selected option to match the value of the product.

Therefore I have to query the selected option of the first 3 dropdowns to get the price.

i.e. I need to know the selected category, manufacturer and model of the product to get the price. This query does seem to work but is not setting the selected value of the price downdown.

In this fiddle, the the self.initialPrice returns 750 (it is returned in an alert box for debugging), but the selected option of the price dropdown stays at 250.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LvLgjjy/

```
function GadgetsViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.gadgetTypes = ko.computed(function () {
        var gadgetTypes = Enumerable.From(gadgets)
            .Select(function (x) { return x.Type })
            .ToArray();
        var types = ko.utils.arrayMap(gadgetTypes, function (item) { return item })
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(types).sort();
    });
    self.selectedGadgetType = ko.observable();


    self.gadgetMakes = ko.computed(function () {
        var gadgetMakes = Enumerable.From(gadgets)
             .Where(function (x) { return x.Type == self.selectedGadgetType() })
            .Select(function (x) { return x.Make })
            .ToArray();
        var makes = ko.utils.arrayMap(gadgetMakes, function (item) { return item })
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(makes).sort();
    });
    self.selectedGadgetMake = ko.observable();


    self.gadgetModels = ko.computed(function () {
        var gadgetModels = Enumerable.From(gadgets)
             .Where(function (x) { return x.Type == self.selectedGadgetType() && x.Make == self.selectedGadgetMake() })
            .Select(function (x) { return x.Model })
            .ToArray();
        var models = ko.utils.arrayMap(gadgetModels, function (item) { return item })
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(models).sort();
    });
    self.selectedGadgetModel = ko.observable();


    self.priceBands = ko.computed(function () {
        var gadgetPriceBands = Enumerable.From(gadgetRates)
             .Where(function (x) { return x.Category == 2 })
            .Select(function (x) { return x.MaxValue })
            .ToArray();
        var priceBands = ko.utils.arrayMap(gadgetPriceBands, function (item) { return item })
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(priceBands);
    });


    self.initialPrice = ko.computed(function () {

        if (self.selectedGadgetType() != null && self.selectedGadgetMake() != null && self.selectedGadgetModel() != null) {
            var price = Enumerable.From(gadgets)
                 .Where(function (x) { return x.Type == self.selectedGadgetType() && x.Make == self.selectedGadgetMake() && x.Model == self.selectedGadgetModel() })
                .Select(function (x) { return x.Value })
                .ToArray();

            alert(price[0]);
            return price[0];

        }
    });

    self.selectedPriceBand = ko.observable(self.initialPrice());
}

ko.applyBindings(new GadgetsViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the selected priceBand as an observable:

```
self.selectedPriceBand = ko.observable();
```

Change the `initialPrice` computed so that it updates this observable, like this:

```
alert(price[0]);
self.selectedPriceBand(price[0]);
return price[0];
```

Remove the line that redefines the observable:

```
self.selectedPriceBand = ko.observable(self.initialPrice());
```

When you do this, the existing observable is destroyed, and the bindings is lost. The newly created observable is not bound to anything.

Your fiddle works if you make this simple changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/4LvLgjjy/1/

Comment: Hi Jotabe. How do I then access the selected value on the dropdown after its been chnaged from its initial value?

Comment: Mmm, ok. I think there is another failure in your code: change the `self.selectedPriceBand = ko.observable(self.initialPrice());` to `self.selectedPriceBand(self.initialPrice())`. If it works, let me now, and I'll explain and improve my answer.

Comment: I found the failing part of your script, but the solution was not exactly the one I told you. I've modified the answer, and your fiddle, and it's working now.